# Call to undefined method My_model::remove_user() Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, methods, undefined

So I am trying to create a function that allows a user to delete their account: hence I want the function to delete all data in the database related to their profile, etc.

In view I have this button:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profiles/remove_user" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning">Delete Account</a>
```

Which lead to my controller "Profiles" which has the following code:

```
function remove_user()
        {  
           $this->load->model("profiles_model");
           $email = $this->session->userdata('email');   
           $this->profiles_model->remove_user($email); 
                      
                $this->load->view('templates/header');
                $this->load->view('pages/homepage');
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
```

Which calls my model Profiles_model which has the following code:

```
function remove_user($email)
              {  
                   $this->db->where('email', $email);  
                   $this->db->delete('profiles');   
}
```

The table where the data is stored is "profiles".

I am also using sessions to pull the user's email.

When I execute, I get this error message: "Message: Call to undefined method Profiles_model::remove_user()"

I dont understand, as I use almost identical code to "Update" user data, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Your methods look fine. You can try rename the method in the Profiles_model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out...my closing "}" tag on my model was ABOVE my function I was trying to call!!!!!!!!!  There is 4 days wasted I will never get back again.